# SQLServer UDF Not Found

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

I have created a Scalar UDF as follows:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fnDiscountPrice
    GO
    CREATE FUNCTION fnDiscountPrice
        (@Item_ID int)
        RETURNS MONEY
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Discount_Price money
        SELECT @Discount_Price = ItemPrice - DiscountAmount
        FROM OrderItems
WHERE ItemID = @Item_ID
    RETURN @Discount_Price
    END
    GO
```

I am trying to use this function to create another function here:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fnItemTotal
GO
CREATE FUNCTION fnItemTotal
    (@Item_ID int)
    RETURNS MONEY
BEGIN
DECLARE @Item_Total MONEY

SELECT @Item_Total = (dbo.fnDiscountPrice(ItemID) * Quantity)
FROM OrderItems
WHERE ItemID = @Item_ID
RETURN @Item_Total
END
GO
SELECT ItemID, ItemPrice, DiscountAmount, Quantity,
    dbo.fnDiscountPrice(ItemId) AS DiscountPrice, dbo.fnItemTotal(ItemID) AS ItemTotal
FROM OrderItems
```

My problem is that the fnDiscountPrice function is giving me an error "Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate 'dbo.fnDiscountPrice', or the name is ambiguous."

I am not sure what the issue is here. The function exists in the programmability folder in database.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is no GO in mysql are you sure this isn't sqlserver?

Comment: OH crap ya its SQLServer my bad. ill update quetion.

Comment: I find both of your functions quite suspect since neither references their `@Item_ID` parameter.

Comment: As you don't schema qualify them when you create them they could have ended up in some other schema than `dbo`. You should use `CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnItemTotal` etc

Comment: I doubt either of those functions are going to work as you expect, unless your table `OrderItems` can only hold one row and **only ever** one row. And if that's the case, `OrderItems` is a some what silly name for something that only contains a **single** item.

Comment: Ok I fixed the reference to @Item_ID in both functions I think(Edited question). Also, in the programmability folder it shows it saved as dbo.fnDiscountPrice. Doesn't that mean its saved in the correct schema?

Comment: Are you seeing this error as an intellisense warning in SSMS or when you actually execute the SQL?

Comment: I'm seeing it as an intellisense warning. I just tried executing it and it worked.. Not sure why I am getting this warning.

Comment: Might be just an intellisense thing then.  Maybe hasn't updated its object lists.

Comment: Update Intellisense with Ctrl + Shift + R. Side point: you should avoid UDFs in favour of *inline* Table Valued Functions. One UDF calling another UDF is just the height of bad performance